# Optimizing a regular expression that causes a Connection Reset error

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

**Expression**

```
$delimiter."".$startTag."\r*\s*((?:(?!{$endTag}).\r*\s*)+)".$endTag.$delimiter
```

**Objective**

The regular expression was written to extract strings that lie in between block codes.

For example
[myblock]
xyz
[/myblock]

The expression above would extract xyz and ignore everything else.

**Problem**

This works like a charm, as long as the string isn't too long, in which case the server throws a Connection Reset error.

Could someone help me figure out why the stack's getting flooded (presumably)? Also, an optimization for the above would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to trim the content between blocks? So `"xyz"` instead of `" xyz "` ?

Comment: Yeah. I also tried it the other way, but it doesn't make much of a difference in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the form of your pattern, you can write:

```
$delimiter . $startTag . "\s*((?:(?!{$endTag}).)*?)\s*" . $endTag . $delimiter . "s"
```

Your orginal pattern doesn't work with long strings, because you don't use, in particular, a non-greedy quantifier *( `*?` instead of `*`)*

The `s` at the end is a modifier that allows `.` to match the newline character.

an other approach:

```
$tag = 'myblock';

$pattern = '~\[' . $tag . ']\s*((?:[^[]+|\[(?!/' . $tag . '))*+)\[/' . $tag .'~';    

// and you use the rtrim function after
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a bunch. Green lights on all unit tests, and it works on browsers as well! I am just starting off with  regular expressions, I can't express enough gratitude for the explanation on why my method failed. You are a star!

Comment: @captainspi: Thanks. Note that the second way can be more efficient in particular if you have to deal with unclosed blocks. *(because it will fail faster)*